# Evitar que se quiten los ceros a la izquierda al crear una lista formada de datos un excel con python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, arraylist

Estoy haciendo la comparación de dos excel, tomo los datos de un excel y comparo si existen en el otro, pero me esta causando problema que hay datos con cero a la izquierda y al convertirlos a una lista se me borran esos ceros y no quiero que eso pase

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

codigosB = pd.read_excel('baz.xlsx')
codigosD = pd.read_excel('cp.xlsx')

cpCep = codigosB.to_numpy().tolist()
cpH = codigosD.to_numpy().tolist()


losQueNoEstan = []
losQueSiEstan = []

for item in cpCep:
    if(item in cpH):
        losQueSiEstan.append(item)
    else:
     losQueNoEstan.append(item)

print(str(item[0]))
```

Este es un ejemplo de los datos que comparo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que intento hacer es tomar los datos de un excel y ver si existen en el otro, si existen los guardo en un arreglo y los imprimo, pero me quita el cero  a la izquierda

**07140 lo deja como 7140**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con eso lo solucionas

```
codigosB = pd.read_excel('baz.xlsx', dtype=str)
codigosD = pd.read_excel('cp.xlsx', dtype=str)
```